# Multithreading and updating UI in Tray-only application,

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I have tray-only application gathering data from service on separate thread and updating context menu with it.

UI can only be updated on UI thread, so I'm trying to Invoke UI update, however without window there is no handle created, so Invoke will throw InvalidOperationException, and InvokeRequired always returns false.

So how can I update my context menu in that case?

EDIT:
I create my tray icon like this:

```
public class TrayIcon : IDisposable
{
    NotifyIcon ni;
    public TrayIcon()
    {
        ni = new NotifyIcon();
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        ni.Icon = Resources.trayIcon;
        ni.Text = "TrayApp";
        ni.Visible = true;
        ni.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenu();

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ni.Dispose();
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        using (TrayIcon icon = new TrayIcon())
        {
            Settings = new Settings();
            icon.Display();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
```

EDIT2: Data is stored inside Obix worker object available staticaly in application, event OnUpdated handlers execute after each update.

```
public class ContextMenu: ContextMenuStrip
{

    private bool _IsSettingsOpen = false;
    private DevicesList DevicesList;

    public ContextMenu()
    {
        DevicesList = new DevicesList();
        DevicesList.Text = "Devices";
        DevicesList.Image = Resources.online;
        Items.Add(DevicesList);
        App.Obix.OnUpdated += InvokeUpdate;
    }

    void InvokeUpdate(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.IsHandleCreated);//<<false
        ContextMenu menu = this;

            MethodInvoker method = delegate
            {
                DevicesList.RePopulate();
            };
            Invoke(method);//<<InvalidOperationException
    }
}

public class DevicesList : ToolStripMenuItem 
{

    public DevicesList()
    {
        RePopulate();
    }

    public void RePopulate()
    {
        IQueryable<ToolStripItem> listed = (IQueryable<ToolStripItem>)DropDownItems.AsQueryable();
        IEnumerable<ToolStripItem> remove = listed.Where(item => !App.Obix.Devices.Contains(new DeviceStatus(item.Name)));
        foreach (ToolStripItem rItem in remove)
        {
            DropDownItems.Remove(rItem);
        }
        IEnumerable<DeviceStatus> add = App.Obix.Devices.Where(device => DropDownItems.IndexOfKey(device.Name) == -1);
        foreach (DeviceStatus aDevice in add)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            item.Name = aDevice.Name;
            item.Text = aDevice.Name;
            DropDownItems.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in DropDownItems)
        {
            DeviceStatus device = App.Obix.Devices.Single(_device => _device.Name == item.Name);
            if (device.State == "down")
                item.Image = Resources.offline;
            else
                item.Image = Resources.online;
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Show the code that updates the UI.

Comment: Your code doesn't have the `Invoke` or `InvokeRequired` that you mentioned.

Comment: @CodeCaster Edited my question

Comment: @mjwills Edited my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` using your `ContextMenuStrip`. It's a `Control`.

**Example**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Form().Icon;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        var contextMenuStrip1 = new ContextMenuStrip();
        notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>  /*Runs in a different thread than UI thread.*/
        {
            if (contextMenuStrip1.InvokeRequired)
                contextMenuStrip1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
                }));
            else
                contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
        };
        timer.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

**Note 1:** `InvokeRequired` property and and `Invoke` method belong to `Control` class. In above code, before showing the `ContextMenuStrip` its `InvokeRequired` returns false, because its handle has not been created. But as soon as you show the `ContextMenuStrip`, its `InvokeRequired` will return true.

**Note 2:** `InvokeRequired` and `Invoke` use the deepest parent available. In the case that the control does't have a parent, the control itself will be used.

Comment: Problem with this is that without window, InvokeRequired will never be true. and changes will be made outside UI thread.

Comment: You can simply test it. Run the application and then right click on the notify icon. It's just a simple example, but proves the solution.

Comment: Turned out it works, and reason why my program does not work lies somewhere else. Thanks.

Comment: In case you could help, I was actually able to reproduce my main problem modifying your example slightly and posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794502/contexmenustrip-oddly-specific-wierd-behaviour

Comment: @RezaAghaei I'm using this technique to access the UI thread in a tray-only app. It worked well until I added a menu item to the ContextMenuStrip. Now I get a null reference exception thrown when returning from ContextMenuStrip.Invoke(). Here's how I add my menu item: 
`_contextMenu.Items.Add("Exit", null, (s, a) => Application.Exit());`
I wondered if that null Image was the cause but adding an image didn't help. Do you have any idea what's happening here?