# ContexMenuStrip oddly-specific weird behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms

I was testing a weird bug I encountered in my app, and finally was able to create a simple reproduction:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var notifyIcon1 = new NotifyIcon();
        notifyIcon1.Icon = new Form().Icon;
        notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
        var contextMenuStrip1 = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem menu1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
        menu1.Text = "test";
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(menu1);
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("t1");
        contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("t2");

        notifyIcon1.ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip1;
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000;
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>  /* Runs in a different thread from UI thread.*/
        {
            if (contextMenuStrip1.InvokeRequired)
                contextMenuStrip1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString() + "extra");
                    menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
                }));
            else
            {
                menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString() + "extra");
                menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
            }
        };
        timer.Start();
        Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Note that the context menu will not open, but doing any of the following allows it to open:

- Removing "extra" dropdown items added per execution. (To be precise
  adding only 0 or 1 per execution works)
- Removing part of code on `InvokeRequired == false` (This allows to add multiple items per execution)
- Removing `t1` and `t2` elements. (It still works without
  additional items in root)

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
additional found condition (thanks to @derape):

- It works if you move else branch to separate method, but not if you use same method in InvokeRequired branch. However using 2 method with different name and same code works.

<sub>Possible workaround could be wearing tigers skin while dancing during full-moon.</sub>

Comment: Hmm that's really weird. I see the same behavior. If I extract the code from the else branch into a method it works...

Comment: @derape Same here, but it won't work if you call same method in InvokeRequired branch.That's honestly bizzare. Also if you then duplicate this method with different name, and use one copy for InvokeRequired branch, and copy in else branch it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [`InvokeRequired`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,d3ab1956c1b4c3db) then you will see there is an explicit check for `IsHandleCreated` which returns `false`. That returned value doesn't means you don't have to invoke, it simply means you can not invoke.

To confuse you even more: you must invoke, but you can't yet.

You can either decide to don't do anything if handle is not created yet (and simply miss items) or organize separate queue to store items until handle is available, similar to:

```
var items = new List<string>();
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (contextMenuStrip1.IsHandleCreated)  // always invoke, but check for handle
        contextMenuStrip1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {

            menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString() + "extra");
            menu1.DropDownItems.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
            contextMenuStrip1.Refresh();
        }));
    else
    {
        lock (items)
        {
            items.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString() + "extra");
            items.Add(e.SignalTime.ToString());
        }
    }
};
contextMenuStrip1.HandleCreated += (s, e) =>
{
    lock (items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            menu1.DropDownItems.Add(item);
        contextMenuStrip1.Refresh();
    }
    items = null;
};
```

Another note: you will need to call `Refresh` if items were added to sub-menu, while menu is opened, but submenu is not yet, odd thing of winforms.

Comment: What you wrote makes sense, but why extracting else branch into separate method allows it to run then? Does it somehow delay execution of code long enough for handle to be created?

Comment: @K.Kowalczyk, I didn't try that, nor I really care what is going to happens if you violate rule "access UI elements in UI thread". Missing notifications, failed event rising, synchronization issues, etc..